# python ndb: what's the best way of implementing categories

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have an `ndb.Model`:

```
class Product(ndb.Model):
    pass
```

- it needs to be categorized in a category tree.
- the categories are NOT dynamic, meaning they cannot change.
- prefferably not implemented using a `class Category(ndb.Model)` 
  because having the categories in the datastore means that you rely on them being there and in the event of testing that means creating them over and over again.

What is the best way of implementing this based on the criteria above ?

Answer (score 1):

Add the category to the Product class as a StringProperty (or an enumerated IntegerProperty if you need to be that space efficient). You can easily have a product belong to more than one category by making it repeated (repeated=True).